# Receive KVO notification even there is no change? This only happens in iOS6, no trouble in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios6, uikit, key-value-observing

Code here:

```
[self.textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

observing method

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"change %@", change);
}
```

Every time I typed in words in the textView, the method just get called even there is no change in contentSize.
**And there is no problem in iOS7.**

What might cause this problem? It is a bug in UIKit?

Comment: your NSLog statement nothing is printed?

Comment: @karthika it just print the same value when line number doesn't change. like {
    kind = 1;
    new = "NSSize: {223, 36}";
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[self.textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:@"mycontext"];  

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSString *oldValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    NSString *newValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    NSLog(@"OldValue %@",oldValue);
    NSLog(@"NewValue %@",newValue);
}
```

Comment: I just print the change, its like this{
    kind = 1;
    new = "NSSize: {223, 36}";
    old = "NSSize: {223, 36}";
}

Comment: you want to change of "text" in textview or contentsize? did you type the long text and short text simultaneously and check?

Comment: I want to change the textview's superview's frame to fit the content, like the system message input view.

Comment: see this link, http://vectorvector.tumblr.com/post/1077884802/how-to-vertically-center-a-uitextview